# Unable to identify elements with "title" attribute using Sahi Pro 6

Tags: html, dom, automated-tests, sahi

With the latest release of Sahi Pro, Sahi Pro 6

One is no longer able to identify the elements using title attribute in an HTML page

like in the case of the tag below:

```
<input  type="button" title="findMe">
```

and as explained here regarding [tweaking of the Sahi APIs](http://sahipro.com/w/tweaking-sahi-apis)

Right in the first example it says you could find

```
this.addAD({tag: "INPUT", type: "button", event:"click", name: "_button", 
attributes: ["value", "name", "id", "index", "className"], 
action: "_click", value: "value"});
```

in sahi/htdocs/spr/concat.js

but I searched **it's no longer available in concat.js** with the Latest version of Sahi. Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Does nobody use Sahi or what? lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been changed a bit and you will find this in userdata/config/accessors_metadata.txt file.

The documentation will be updated with a new release coming very soon.

Comment: Thanks, this seems to be helpful.

Comment: Nope, not at all. It Worked.